# Trying to add an override to a Form inside a DLL

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Main program is *MDIParent*. 
A Menu button calls a **Form from a DLL** and opens inside the MDI Form

For some reason, if a form is *maximized* inside the MDIParent when it is closed, it throws an error.
I've hacked a workaround in local forms designer code by adding 
`Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal` inside the Dispose function

How do I do the same for the DLL FORM without recreating the dll
I just need to overwrite the dispose Subroutine

Application is mostly VB.NET but, If answer is in c# i will take that too

In case someone is familiar with the error:

[image: Error]

Comment: `For some reason, if a form is maximized inside the MDIParent when it is closed, it throws an error.` why? I've never had this happen

Comment: Can you show some code? I've tried to close a maximized MDI child and it doesn't raise any exception. Can't replicate.

Comment: not sure what causes it, its a large project. But thats the workaround i used. The question is how to apply this workaround to a DLL Form

Comment: So I guess you mean you have a form defined in a DLL, but the important fact is that you don't have the ability to change the Form's code, correct?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to actually figure out the exception and stop it happening rather than jumping through hoops to build workarounds?

Comment: was hoping i could add handler or something similar

Comment: Must we guess what the error is?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway doubt it will help you but here it is (updated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's hope your MDI child form is not marked `NotInheritable` (`sealed` in c#). Then you can just make a new class which inherits it, and override `Dispose`

```vb
' Code in Project A

Public Class frm1
    ' specific code
End Class
```

```vb
' Code in Project B
' Add a reference to Project A

Public Class frm2
    Inherits A.frm1
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then instead of creating a new `A.frm1`, you will create a `B.frm2`.

```vb
' Dim myFrm As New A.frm1()
Dim myFrm As New B.frm2()
myFrm.MdiParent = Me
myFrm.Show()
```

Comment: It seems that the issue did not apply to DLL forms for some reason, but I will accept this answer for anyone who does find similar issues

Comment: @EssKay could you elaborate on what a "DLL form" is?

Comment: Sure. There is a Project with a form  **frm1**. It is created as a **A.DLL**.  In a second project, you import the DLL & call that form **Dim f as new A.frm1  f.show()**

Comment: @EssKay ok that's all fine and good. So it's in **project A** and you don't have access to the code. That's an important point, and why you might want to use inheritance to extend the class. Whether it's in a different assembly or in the same assembly (dll or exe) doesn't matter as long as you can't edit the code :) . I'll update my answer according to your naming in your comment.

Comment: technically, I have accesss to the code, but that DLL is used in many projects, so updating each one of them with new DLL will be far more work. I don't have that error in other projects

Comment: @EssKay ah, then it shouldn't hurt, right? If you do update A.frm1 to fix the windows in dispose, will it have any impact on the other projects which use it? If I were in your shoes (with limited knowledge of your environment, of course) I would just edit A.frm1 so it works with all calling classes. Inheritance is still a hack but I had assumed you couldn't edit the A library.

Comment: at the moment, forms from DLLs are not giving me issues. it seems to only be local forms. But i accepted the answer, in case it helps someone else. feel free to rate the question :)